# setCurrentItem не вызывает OnPageChangeListener

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Есть ViewPager, страницы которого прокручиваются програмно с помощью setCurrentItem(). На последней странице, при вызове setCurrentItem(getCurrentItem + 1) не вызываются методы OnPageChangeListener. При этом, если листать вручную все работает. Есть ли другой способ смены страниц, которые вызывают методы слушателя даже на последней странице?

Код метода внутри кнопки, при которой осуществляется смена страницы

```
@Override
public void nextPage() {
    this.setCurrentItem(this.getCurrentItem() + 1,true);
}
```

Код Слушателя (при свайпе на последней странице вызывается другая активность)

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        int lastPosition;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            lastPosition = position;
            boolean isEnable = (pageType != TEST_PAGE_TYPE);
            pager.setPagingEnabled(isEnable);
        }

        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            Log.i(TAG,"state is: " + state);
            if ((state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) &&
                    (lastPosition == pager.getChildCount() - 1)){
                Intent intent = ChooseWayActivity.newIntent(
                        TheoryLessonPagerActivity.this,ChooseWayActivity.START_NEW_TEST);
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CHOOSE_WAY);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Не совсем ясно в чём проблема. У вас не вызывается слушатель при выборе страницы с индексом 2, при кол-ве страниц 3? Или при индексе 3 при том же количестве страниц? Насколько мне известно, слушатель не вызывается при выборе 0 страницы. Это можно обойти вручную вызвав метод слушателя. Для последней страницы такого не наблюдал. Возможно, вы что-то не так делаете. Покажите код

Comment: Слушатель не вызывается при вызове метода setCurrentItem(getCurrentItem() + 1) при нахождении на странице с индексом 2 при количестве страниц 3. При этом, если листать вручную, все работает. Код добавил

Comment: По идее вы при этом находитесь на последней странице и либо ничего не должно происходить или должна программа падать по ошибке выхода за пределы массива. У вас же, получается, не вызывается `onPageSelected` c `position` 3 при кол-ве страниц 3? И вызывается, если вы делаете это вручную? Оно не должно вручную вызываться. Разве что с `position` 2... Или вы про onPageScrollStateChanged? Поясните какую вы задачу хотите решить.

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно просто создать переменную для ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener и программно вызвать у неё нужный метод вместо вызова this.setCurrentItem(this.getCurrentItem() + 1,true);

Comment: мне необходимо, чтобы при попытке свайпа на последней странице (position 2, количество страниц 3) вызывалась другая активность. При ручном свайпе я решил это отслеживанием onPageScrollStateChanged при position = количеству страниц( SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING вызывается в любом случае, первая либо последняя страница).  При этом мне необходимо чтобы смена страниц пейджера осуществлялась автоматически , в этом случае  onPageScrollStateChanged не вызывается.

Comment: Со стороны пользователя все выглядит следующим образом - есть тест, с ворпосом и кнопками с ответами, пока кнопка не нажата, листать нельзя. При нажатии на кнопку сообщается правильный ли ответ и автоматически перелистывает на следующий. При ответе на последний вопрос выводится результат в виде другой активности

Comment: По идее вам надо разнести логику обработки переключения/скрола страниц от логики открытия активити другого. Т.е. сделать метод, который будет проверять последняя сейчас страница или нет и листать на следующую или открывать новую активити. Используемый вами сейчас способ - концептуально неправильный. Логика открытия экрана не должна быть жестко завязана на слушатели скрола/переключения страниц, а может лишь вызываться из них.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [ЮрийСПБ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1), лучшее решение создать переменную для ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener и программно вызвать у неё onPageScrollStateChanged(ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) перед setCurrentItem(this.getCurrentItem() + 1,true);
 Оставил сет метод из-за особеностей реализации, при подобной проблеме можно выбрать onPageSelected(int position)